# Retrieve second level contacts LinkedIn API

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

It's possible to retrieve first level contacts of one of my LinkedIn contacts using LinkedIn API.

If i pass one of my contacts name or email, it is possible to retrieve his/her first level contacts, i'm using PHP as my development platform.

Help is highly welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You can only search for 2nd level/degree connections with the [People Search API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api), and you need approval before you can use it. There is no way to get a full list of all 2nd level connections without search parameters.

Search for "facets" in the API docs, especially with the value "S" (Second Degree Connections).

Answer (score 2):

The profile fields for the LinkedIn API are documented here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

As you can see, connections are not available for second degree (or further) connections, only for the logged-in and authenticated user.

Comment: but the document said, second degree can get the first_name,last_name etc

Comment: You can get the first name or second name of someone who is your second degree connection.  You cannot, however retrieve the connections of someone other than the authenticated user.  There's a difference between asking for information about someone who was retrieved (by a search or whatever) who happens to be 2 degrees away - which is supported - and asking for the connections of your connections, which is not.