# How to use facets and values with linkedin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-gem

I am using the linkedin gem and trying to pull second degree connections only. This is said to be done by using the people search api and the network,S facet. S is for "Second degree connections."

The problem is that the documentation explains doing this with something like:

```
GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?facet=network,S
```

I am using the linkedin gem so I tried doing something like:

```
client.search( { :facets => [:network, :S] }, :people )
```

but I get a `(400): Unknown facet code {network+S}`

If I change it to `client.search({ facets: ["network,S"] }, :people)`,

I get `(400): Unknown facet code {S}`

If I just do client.search( { :facets => [:network] }, :people ), it returns all connections. with codes F,S,A, and O.

Any help here?

Also, when it does return, it only returns 10 or so. I saw a way to paginate through but then I have too many api calls. Is there a way to pull them all in one call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin no longer supports retrieval of second level connections.

Check out this post:
[Retrieve second level contacts LinkedIn API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465768/retreive-second-level-contacts-linked-in-api)